# linux bashrc alias to open terminals and run individual scripts

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I am trying to make a shortcut alias that does the following for me:

1. opens a new terminal and inside that new terminal it cd's to a directory and runs a script.
2. At the same time, opens another new terminal and inside that new terminal it cd's to a directory and runs a script.

I have tried the following:

```
alias launchmystuff='cd /path/to/directory1/ && gnome-terminal &&     ./myscript1.sh; cd /path/to/directory2/ && gnome-terminal && ./myscript2.sh'
```

There are two problems with this:

1. It opens 1 terminal and is waiting for myscript1.sh to finish BEFORE launching the second terminal.
2. The terminal that opens and runs the script does not have "possession" of the script that is running. The original terminal that the alias is typed into has "possession" of the scripts that are running. So if I close any of the newly created terminals, the script will not die.

Ideally I would like two terminals to open at once, each running their unique scripts, and for each of them to kill the script when I close their respective terminals.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the script as an argument to `gnome-terminal`, rather than running it in the current shell after starting `gnome-terminal`. As usual, you should use a shell function instead of an alias here.

```
launchmystuff () {
  cd /path/to/directory1/ && gnome-terminal -e ./myscript1.sh
  cd /path/to/directory2/ && gnome-terminal -e ./myscript2.sh
}
```

Comment: Hell yeah that worked! Thank you! I really appreciate it! What is the reason for making it a shell function?

Comment: Briefly, because aliases suck.